# C# ASP.NET MVC Crystal Report parameter value not being passed to report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, crystal-reports

C# ASP.NET MVC web application - Crystal Report parameter fields are not showing value in report PDF.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "BOMCosting.rpt"));

rd.SetParameterValue("@vCom", CompanyID);
rd.SetParameterValue("@vItem", item);
rd.SetParameterValue("@t_citg", groups);
rd.SetParameterValue("@v_NItem", items);
rd.SetParameterValue("@vCust", Customer);

rd.SetDataSource(dt);               
rd.Refresh();

Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(stream, "application/pdf", FileName + ".pdf");
```

Comment: rd.SetParameterValue("@vCust", Customer) -> vCust value not showing in pdf.

Comment: check parameters in your profile call whether it is passing correct @dhuv

Comment: yes, it is call same as above.

Comment: Can you Verify your `BOMCosting.rpt` and check @dhuv? if that also not working, just try `Set Datasource Location`

Answer (score 0):

**hey Can you please verify report with latest DB (if you are using stored procedure please verify), if report is not updated with latest please update option will be Available in[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the data source first before passing the parameter. As simple as that.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "BOMCosting.rpt"));

rd.SetDataSource(dt);               

rd.SetParameterValue("@vCom", CompanyID);
rd.SetParameterValue("@vItem", item);
rd.SetParameterValue("@t_citg", groups);
rd.SetParameterValue("@v_NItem", items);
rd.SetParameterValue("@vCust", Customer);

Stream stream = 
rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(stream, "application/pdf", FileName + ".pdf");
```